# Strange sorting in Stata after doing encode

Tags: stata

Variable X used to be string. So I used `encode` command to make it non-string.

But after that when I sort it, it's sorted in this way.

```
1000
10000
10001
10003
10005
1003
```

But usually, it should be sorted like

```
1000
1001
1003
1005
```

Why is sorting so strange after doing `encode`?

And it appears `1003` created from `encode` and `1003` in `using` dataset are considered different numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strange at all. Right near the top of `help encode` Stata tells you "Do not use `encode` if *varname* contains numbers that merely happen to be stored as strings".

`encode` maps strings in alphabetical (here alphanumeric)  order to numeric values 1 up (unless you specify otherwise with a `label()` option).

So `"1000"` will sort before `"10000"` before `"1001"`, and so forth.

You probably need `destring` but why was the variable read as string? That's what you need to worry about.

`encode` is for strings when you want a numeric equivalent. So `"cat" "dog" "frog" "toad"` will map to 1 2 3 4 and the string values will become value labels.

`destring` is for mistaken strings. The variable should be numeric, but something went wrong on reading the data. So, what was it that went wrong? Common errors include

1. Header data from a spreadsheet that should be a variable label (or ignored) got read in as data.
2. Codes for missing data such as `NA` that make sense to people or to some other program but do not correspond to Stata representations of missing.
3. Garbage of some kind.

To check for problems, you could look at the values that wouldn't translate to numbers:

```
 tab whatever if missing(real(whatever))
```

Comment: Here's [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987980/convert-string-date-variable-to-numeric/49988139#49988139) with an example where the use of `encode` is not appropriate